# How clicking on a thumbnail image produces a larger image so quickly

Tags: android, image

I am developing an android app which needs to load a big image quickly. Using Instagram on Android I have noticed a feature they have that I cannot figure out how it works. Instagram users have a feed which displays usually a scroll list with a bunch of small thumbnails:

[image]

When you click an thumbnail image you get sent to another page(assuming fragment) that shows a bigger version of the image which appears instantly (to the human eye it looks instant)

You can scroll through all these thumbnails which means a lot of thumbnails display very quickly which I can understand because the images are small and sending over the network would be relatively quick. The problem I am understanding is how the larger images appear so quickly!? When the app downloaded the thumbnails are the larger images downloaded at the same time (I do not think this is the case because it would be such a waste of network traffic since most users on't click on every thumbnail? What technique is being used to have such fast response times for large images? I thought it maybe because of cache, but it happens when I click a picture I have never seen before.I is so fast it looks like it even is not hitting the network.

Answer (score 0):

> How clicking on a thumbnail image produces a a larger image so quickly?

- Uses faster CDN networks to fetch images
- Uses `Fresco` for image loading which implements progressive image loading
- Uses `RecyclerView`, image loading is triggered when ever you stop scrolling.
- Probably uses webp and jpg image formats
- Images are cached for later use